# Sklearn overfitting

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a data set containing 1000 points each with 2 inputs and 1 output. It has been split into 80% for training and 20% for testing purpose. I am training it using sklearn support vector regressor. I have got 100% accuracy with training set but results obtained with test set are not good. I think it may be because of overfitting. Please can you suggest me something to solve the problem.

Comment: Is there any reason for the choice of SVR ?

Comment: It is because it has various number of kernels which can be then used to fit non-linear data properly.

Comment: The main idea behind machine learning algorithms is to create non linear models. SVR is quite slow to converge. The fact that SVR has many kernels, each with different parameters makes it even slower (as you have no real choice but to make a gridsearch, testing all combinations of parameters). That is why I asked you the idea behind this choice.

Comment: So can you suggest me anything which is better than SVR?

Answer (score 2):

You may be right: if your model scores very high on the training data, but it does poorly on the test data, it is usually a symptom of overfitting. You need to retrain your model under a different situation. I assume you are using train_test_split provided in sklearn, or a similar mechanism which guarantees that your split is fair and random. So, you will need to tweak the hyperparameters of SVR and create several models and see which one does best on your test data.

If you look at the SVR documentation, you will see that it can be initiated using several input parameters, each of which could be set to a number of different values. For the simplicity, let's assume you are only dealing with two parameters that you want to tweak: 'kernel' and 'C', while keeping the third parameter 'degree' set to 4. You are considering 'rbf' and 'linear' for kernel, and 0.1, 1, 10 for C. A simple solution is this:

```
for kernel in ('rbf', 'linear'):
    for c in (0.1, 1, 10):
        svr = SVR(kernel=kernel, C=c, degree=4)
        svr.fit(train_features, train_target)
        score = svr.score(test_features, test_target)
        print kernel, c, score
```

This way, you can generate 6 models and see which parameters lead to the best score, which will be the best model to choose, given these parameters.

A simpler way is to let sklearn to do most of this work for you, using [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) (or [RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV.html)):

```
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':(0.1, 1, 10)}
clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(degree=4), parameters)
clf.fit(train_features, train_target)
print clf.best_score_
print clf.best_params_
model = clf.best_estimator_ # This is your model
```

I am working on a little tool to simplify using sklearn for small projects, and make it a matter of configuring a yaml file, and letting the tool do all the work for you. It is available on my [github](https://github.com/happyhuman/sler) account. You might want to take a look and see if it helps.

Finally, your data may not be linear. In that case you may want to try using something like [PolynomialFeatures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) to generate new nonlinear features based on the existing ones and see if it improves your model quality.

Answer (score 1):

Try fitting your data using training data split Sklearn K-Fold cross-validation, this provides you a fair split of data and better model , though at a cost of performance , which should really matter for small dataset and where the priority is accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

A few hints:

- Since you have only two inputs, it would be great if you plot your data. Try either a scatter with alpha = 0.3 or a heatmap.
- Try [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), as mentioned by @shahins.

  - Especially, try different values for the `C` parameter. As mentioned in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#complexity), if you have a lot of noisy observations you should decrease it. It corresponds to regularize more the estimation.
  - If it's taking too long, you can also try [RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)
  - As a side note from @shahins answer (I am not allowed to add comments), both implementations are not equivalent. GridSearchCV is better since it performs cross-validation in the training set for tuning the hyperparameters. Do not use the test set for tuning hyperparameters!
- Don't forget to scale your data